# VK API Работа с методом messages.getByConversationMessageId

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я пишу бота, мне нужно получить сообщения в беседе по id. Это глупо, но у меня не получается сформировать тестовый запрос. Я понимаю, что peer_id должен быть chat peer. Но что такое chat peer?

Ссылка на документацию https://vk.com/dev/messages.getByConversationMessageId

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getByConversationMessageId) заглянуть? Там же четко написано что такое `peer_id`. Цитата: `Для пользователя: id пользователя.`, `Для групповой беседы: 2000000000 + id беседы.`, `Для сообщества: -id сообщества.` (обратите внимание на минус в начале). Вроде все понятно) Называется это "Идентификатором назначения" и их может быть несколько (разделенные запятой).

Comment: Так смотрел (забыл ссылку на документацию прикрепить.) Я указал реальные айди. 106.. - мой, 172 - сообщество

Answer (score 0):

За давностью вопроса уже не помню точной причины, но суть была в том, что то ли метод устарел то ли справку забыли обновить, в общем вопрос к разрабам вк, которые вовремя не обновляют документацию